# declare variabe in PROC SQL (SAS)

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to use a variable on PROC SQL but i cannot find a proper way through the internet. I just want to apply the following code of T-SQL on PROC SQL:

```
 declare @example as int;
set @example=2;
select * from {table} where {column}=@example;
go
```

How can i apply this code on PROC SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translation to SAS SQL is to use a macro variable, the code looks pretty similar, need to wrap it in a PROC SQL block though.

```
%let example=2;

proc sql;
select *
from table
where variable=&example;
quit;
```

EDIT: my original reference to the macro variable was incorrect, use an ampersand in SAS not @ symbol.

Comment: Many thanks, i could not find that implementation through the web. I was able to find only implementations with really MANY lines of code which is quite irritating. Do you have in your mind any specific Book or guide for SAS SQL? i can only find books that are not helpful

Comment: Here's a quick decent intro in SAS Macros. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/sas_macros_introduction/